# Best Ultimate Full Cheapest Backup Software

Tags: backup

sorry about the long title!
I have a windows server 2003. I want to a cheap backup software that will save every single thing in the machine: files, regsitry, user accounts & settings, down to the single byte! I prefer to have dvd storages at the end to restore from. I don't want to even have to worry about Admin setup or rerun software installations or anything like that.
So, if the server crashes totally, I will be able to bring it back to exact mirror of how it was before it crashed.

I want to be able to insert dvd and reboot to get everything back.

Does the Backup utility on server 2003 do that? If not, does a software like this exist?? If not, what is the next closest thing?

thanks!

Comment: You should look at clonezilla!

Comment: why don't you post it as an answer so i can mark it as the answer.

Comment: Feedback: I just got to start using clonezilla. I have been using it numerous times. It is so easy and so amazing! It brought my images exactly (down to the byte!). It was a life saver. Thank you so much Eugene!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Request, I repost my comment as an answer:

Look at [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) - this is the physical equivalent of a Snapshot in virtual world.